# {guzzle-services} How to use middlewares with GuzzleClient client AS OPPOSED TO directly with raw GuzzleHttp\Client?

Tags: guzzle6

My middleware need is to:

- add an extra query param to requests made by a REST API client derived from `GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient`

I cannot do this directly when invoking APIs through the client because `GuzzleClient` uses an API specification and it only passes on "legal" query parameters. Therefore I must install a middleware to intercept HTTP requests **after** the API client prepares them.

The track I am currently on:

- `$apiClient->getHandlerStack()-push($myMiddleware)`

The problem:

I cannot figure out the RIGHT way to assemble the functional Russian doll that `$myMiddleware` must be. This is an **insane** gazilliardth-order function scenario, and the **exact right** way the function should be written seems to be **different** from the extensively documented way of doing things when working with `GuzzleHttp\Client` directly. No matter what I try, I end up having wrong things passed to some layer of the matryoshka, causing an argument type error, or I end up returning something wrong from a layer, causing a type error in Guzzle code.

I made a carefully weighted decision to give up trying to understand. Please just give me a boilerplate solution **for `GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient`, as opposed to `GuzzleHttp\Client`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HandlerStack` that is used to handle middleware in `GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient` can either transform/validate a command before it is serialized or handle the result after it comes back.  If you want to modify the command after it has been turned into a request, but before it is actually sent, then you'd use the same method of Middleware as if you weren't using `GuzzleClient` - create and attach middleware to the `GuzzleHttp\Client` instance that is passed as the first argument to `GuzzleClient`.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\Description;

class MyCustomMiddleware
{
    public function __invoke(callable $handler) {
        return function (RequestInterface $request, array $options) use ($handler) {
            // ... do something with request
            return $handler($request, $options);
        }
    }
}


$handlerStack = HandlerStack::create();
$handlerStack->push(new MyCustomMiddleware);
$config['handler'] = $handlerStack;

$apiClient = new GuzzleClient(new Client($config), new Description(...));
```

The boilerplate solution for `GuzzleClient` is the same as for `GuzzleHttp\Client` because regardless of using Guzzle Services or not, your request-modifying middleware needs to go on `GuzzleHttp\Client`.

Comment: Yes, I got confused by both GuzzleClient and GuzzleHttp\Client supporting middlewares. I was trying to push the http client middleware onto the GuzzleClient's handler stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$handler->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function(){...});
```

Of sorts to manipulate the request. I'm not 100% certain this is the thing you're looking for.  But I assume you can add your extra parameter to the Request in there.

```
 private function createAuthStack()
 {
     $stack = HandlerStack::create();
     $stack->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
         return $request->withHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " . $this->accessToken);
     }));
     return $stack;
 }
```

More Examples here:  https://hotexamples.com/examples/guzzlehttp/Middleware/mapRequest/php-middleware-maprequest-method-examples.html